# Windows 2008 File Share

Tags: windows-server-2008, share

I have 3 Windows 2008 Standard servers in my system with no domain controller. Two of the servers are running a NLB cluster and the third server is a file server that the web servers connect to. I want to store my source code on the file server and point the IIS config to the network file share. The web sites also need access to a file share on the file server.

I was able to share the network drive and access while logged into either of the web servers but my web apps are unable to access the file share -  I assume due to permissions. Does anybody know the correct way to do this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Modify the file permissions on the file server (for the shared folders), and add the NETWORK SERVICE user on the web server some rights to read.

Try adding a user with permissions in the form: MACHINENAME\USERNAME.

Or, you can create a special group with the right permissions to access the folders, and then add the remote user to that group.

Comment: Since the web server and file server's user directory is independent of each other, how would I add web server's user account to the file server's share?

Comment: Tried adding MACHINENAME/ACCOUNT but the server refuses to add it when it checks the name against the internal user store.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add an account to each machine with the same username/password and use that account for the IIS anonymous user, the application pools and the file share.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that some source control softwares have their own built in webserver (such as Subversion)  and so I am unclear as to why you want to host your source via IIS.

Also,  I would recommend just run the IIS FTP server on the server machine and then map your drives from the client machines using a FTP drive mapping.   This way you skip the use of NetBIOS protocol.